# Issue Deploying with Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-forge

I am trying to deploy a Laravel PHP Project with Laravel Forge.  I have connected to my repository on github correctly.  However, when I hit deploy, if I go to the public IP for the site, I just see:

```
"No input file specified."
```

on the page.

I do not know why it is exhibiting this behavior.

If I go to the latest deployment log, I see:

```
/home/forge/.forge/provision-433327.sh: line 1: cd: /home/forge/default/laravel: No such file or directory
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/forge
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Could not open input file: artisan
```

However, I do have a composer.json file in my laravel folder....

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like the server directory has been setup correctly. Did you change anything manually? If I was you, I would delete the server and re-provision it again. Let Forge do everything - don't manually change any folders etc

Comment: @user1072337 I'm getting this same problem. When creating the site the folder is made, but when I link it to the repo and do a deploy the folder gets deleted and the above message appears. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the /home/forge/default/laravel directory doesn't exist. Could you ssh in and verify that the directory exists?

These are the commands that the default forge deploy script runs:

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install
php artisan migrate --force
```

It looks like your deploy script is navigating to **/home/forge/default/laravel** instead.